# Magento 2: change the "Contact Us" page layout

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, cms-pages

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop and  I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

I've changed the layout of my homepage to *2 columns with left bar* from `Content -> Pages`. I need to do the same for the *Contact Us* page.

As can be seen in the image below, I don't have this option for the  *Contact Us* page:

[image]

What (XML) file must I edit to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Contacts US is not a cms page** and it is an  Module page which is manage from **Magento_Contacts** module.

So, if you want to changes the layout then you should do some code.

Create`contact_index_index.xml` if does not exits at

> app/design/frontend/{ThemeVendor}/{Themename}/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml

***Then create add  below codes for changes the layout***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 </page>
```

**Here, i have set contact us page layout as 1column**

```
layout="1column"
```

**you can use**

```
 - layout="2columns-left" if want to changes to 2 columns left



 - layout="2columns-right" if want to changes to 2 columns right



 - layout="3columns" if want to changes to 3 columns
```

Comment: This is my question: what file(s) shall I change?

Comment: ***So, Do you want to changes page layout for all cms page or Contacts US page?***

Comment: "Contact US" page.

Comment: Is there a way I can add content from the Magento admin above the contact form? Something like: _Address: 914-3472 Quisque Rd, Rome_.

Comment: Create a CMS static block and  add this block usin WIDGet

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml

find this line

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

and replace with

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

If you want to override this layout file in your custom module, 
create

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/contact_index_index.xml

and apply the changes as given above.

Don't forget to use sequence in your custom module's **etc/module.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Contact"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: I would like to _overwrite_ the `contact_index_index.xml` file from the theme. How can I do that?

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: I don't have a custom module. I have a custom theme: `app/design/frontend/myCompany/my_theme`

Comment: if you added the answer for theme also

Comment: create `app/design/frontend/myCompany/my_theme/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml` and do the changes as given in the answer.

Comment: I did this `<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"></page>`. No change in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

To edit contact us page you need to edit the form.phtml listed in `\vendor\magento\module-contact\view\frontend\layout\contact_index_index.xml`

Comment: Its not recommended to edit vendor files...